# How Polymer Hero Transition works

Tags: html, css, polymer, shadow-dom

First off I'm having a tough time understanding the fundamentals of the hero-transition within Polymer. I am attempting to build a hero transition card like the one in the example provided by them, which can be found [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-animated-pages/demo.html).
Below I've built the mini card and I'm just trying to understand the transition and how the larger card works with the smaller one.

My specific question is, how does the transition bind to each element? Do I need to complete the CSS for both before I can begin playing with the core-animated-pages? Does having an embedded template matter?

Any guidance would be extremely helpful.

```
<script src="../components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-animated-pages/transitions/hero-transition.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-image/core-image.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
<polymer-element name="chip-card">
    <template>
        <style>
            #page2 {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #paper_shadow {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
                font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: white;
            }
            #chip_body {
                height: 400px;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: aqua;
                color: black;
            }
            #chip_top {
                background-color: deeppink;
                background-image: url();
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: center center;
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }
            #chip_bottom {
                background-color: #fbfbfb;
                width: 100%;
                height: 20%;
                position: relative;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            #text {
                padding-left: 5%;
                padding-right: 2.5%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #coreImage {
                display: block;
            }
            #card_container {
                width: 70%;
                height: 600px;
                background-color: aqua;
                color: black;
            }
            #card_right {
                height: 100%;
                width: 30%;
            }
            #card_left {
                background-color: darkblue;
                height: 100%;
                width;
                70%;
            }
            #card_left_top {
                padding-right: 20px;
                padding-top: 20px;
                background-color: skyblue;
            }
            #circle {
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: red;
            }
            #header_text {
            }
            #card_content {
                width:100%;
                background-color: lightcoral;
            }
        </style>
        <core-animated-pages transitions="hero-transition" selected={{page}}>
            <section>
                <paper-shadow z="1" id='paper_shadow' on-mouseover="{{raise}}" on-mouseout="{{lower}}" animated=true; hero-p="" on-tap="{{transition}}">
                    <div id="chip_body" hero-id="chip_body" vertical layout center justified>
                        <div id="chip_top" flex>
                            <div id="coreImage">
                                <content select="#core-image"></content>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="chip_bottom" vertical layout start-justified>
                            <div id='text'>
                                <content select="#chip_bottom"></content>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </paper-shadow>
            </section>
            <section id="page2">
                <div id="card_container" hero-id="chip_body" on-tap="{{transition}}" hero=""></div>
            </section>
        </core-animated-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('chip-card', {
            page: 0,

            raise: function() {
                this.$.paper_shadow.setZ(2);
            },
            lower: function() {
                this.$.paper_shadow.setZ(1);
            },
            transition: function(e) {
                if (this.page === 0) {
                    this.$.paper_shadow = e.currentTarget;
                    this.page = 1;
                } else {
                    this.page = 0;
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Your link leads to http://127.0.0.1:54939/html/chip_to_card.html, please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are actually very close to a working transition with the code you have.

I've implemented a more complicated hero transition on my website and took some code from there to get yours to work.

```html
    <core-animated-pages transitions="hero-transition" selected={{page}}>
        <section>
            <paper-shadow z="1" id='paper_shadow' on-mouseover="{{raise}}" on-mouseout="{{lower}}" hero-p on-tap="{{transition}}">
                <div id="chip_body" hero-id="chip_body" hero vertical layout center justified>
                    <div id="chip_top" flex>
                        <div id="coreImage">
                            <content select="#core-image"></content>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="chip_bottom" vertical layout start-justified>
                        <div id='text'>
                            <content select="#chip_bottom"></content>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </paper-shadow>
        </section>
        <section id="page2">
            <div id="card_container" hero-id="chip_body" on-tap="{{transition}}" hero></div>
        </section>
    </core-animated-pages>
```

I've made but a few adjustments.

- First off, any hero parent element, with the `hero-p` attribute, should     contain just that attribute. So no need for the quotation marks :)
  `<paper-shadow hero-p .. >`
- Every element that's part of the Hero transition, needs a `hero` attribute.
  Again, without the quotation marks. `<div id="chip_body" .. hero .. >`
- And the same thing goes for the element you're transitioning to.
  `<div id="card_container" .. hero .. >`

---

I've put a working version of your code on my website.
There's page containing the `<chip-card>` element and a second page containing the working template file.

[Index page](http://michielsteegmans.me/stackoverflow.html)
[Template file](http://michielsteegmans.me/elements/chip-card.html)

**Please note** : I edited the reference to `webcomponentsjs` to conform with my folder structure.

Feel free to ask me if there's anything else!